# redirect on Jquery Ajax success not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, webmethod

Jquery Code:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    url: "ManageUsers/ValidateReportUsers.aspx/allocateSessionRedirect",
                    data: '{id:"'+flag+'"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.d == true) {
                            alert("You will now be redirected.");

                            window.location.href = "/DownloadReport.aspx";

                        }
                    }

                });

Web Method code :

 public static bool allocateSessionRedirect (int id)
         {
             // set of codes here
               return true;

         }
```

The browser displays alert message "You will now be redirected." But does not execute `window.location.href = "/DownloadReport.aspx";`
I have tried `window.location="/DownloadReport.aspx";` as well as `window.location.assign("/DownloadReport.aspx");`

but did not work. Please advice.

Comment: Try removing the alert dialog and see if you face the same issue. Use a console log, rather than an alert dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the button property as below:-

OnClientClick="return false"

The button is posting back. Hence, the redirect is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `location.assign("URL");` instead. It should work.

Hope this helps.